# Sort range Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, ubuntu, range

everyone. I have some questions about sorting in bash. I am working with Ubuntu 14.04 .
The first question is: why if I have file some.txt with this content:

```
b 8
b 9
a 8
a 9
```

And when I type this :

```
sort -n -k 2 some.txt
```

the result will be:

```
a 8
b 8
a 9
b 9
```

which means that the file is sorted first to the second field and after that to the first field, but I thought that is will stay stable i.e.

```
b 8
a 8
...
...
```

Maybe if two rows are equal it is applied lexicographical sort or what ?

The second question is: why the following doesn`t working:

```
sort -n -k 1,2 try.txt
```

The file try.txt is like this:

```
8 2
8 11
8 0
8 5
9 2
9 0
```

The third question is not actally for sorting, but it appears when I try to do this:

```
sort blank.txt > blank.txt
```

After this the blank.txt file is empty. Why is that ?

Comment: I fixed your formatting. Please use the EDIT link to see what I did.  Also, please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for tips on writing good questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Apparently GNU sort is not stable by default: add the `-s` option

   > Finally, as a last resort when all keys compare equal, sort compares entire lines as if no ordering options other than --reverse (-r) were specified. The --stable (-s) option disables this last-resort comparison so that lines in which all fields compare equal are left in their original relative order.
   >   (https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html)
2. There's no way to answer your question if you don't show the text file
3. Redirections are handled by the shell *before* handing off control to the program. The `>` redirection will truncate the file if it exists. After that, you are giving an empty file to `sort`

---

for #2, you don't actually explain what's not working. Expanding your sample data, this happens

```
$ cat try.txt
8 2
8 11
9 2
9 0
11 11
11 2
$ cat try.txt
8 2
8 11
9 2
9 0
11 11
11 2
```

I assume you want to know why the 2nd column is not sorted numerically. Let's go back to the sed manual:

> ‘-n’
>   ‘--numeric-sort’
>   ‘--sort=numeric’
>
> > Sort numerically. **The number begins each line** and consists of ...

Looks like using `-n` only sorts the first column numerically. After some trial and error, I found this combination that sorts each column numerically:

```
$ sort -k1,1n -k2,2n try.txt 
8 2
8 11
9 0
9 2
11 2
11 11
```

Comment: [Suggested Link for #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file)

Comment: Probably the algorithm is unstable for good reasons: I guess it comes with a performance penalty (not in time complexity, but the algorithm becomes more complex and requires more instructions).

Comment: Thanks a lot, glenn jackman. I thought that this is something basic, but obviously it's not. First time I tried different ways, but they didn't work. Your way is working great, but I still don't understand the why this doesn't work

    sort -k 1n,2n try.txt

The syntax is weird. I will be glad if someone can tells me in what way does this works.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention that this is working too:
    sort -k 1n -k 2n try.txt
but it is also inconvenient.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem There's more than one reason for a sort algorithm to be "unstable". The first is an optimisation, which I think you're alluding to. A sort might be faster if it does not need to preserve any aspect of the input data's original ordering. In this case, being unstable might result in an unpredictable or random ordering within the key equivalence classes. The second, which seems to be the case for gnu `sort`, is to ensure a consistent result; the 'last-resort' stage does _extra_ work to sort the key equivalence classes whose order would _otherwise_ have been stably preserved.